# Can't install ns2 in Ubuntu with the below error as shown in picture

Tags: software-installation, ns2

I can't install ns2 in Ubuntu with the below error as shown in the picture.

[image: Terminal screenshot]

```
(1) You MUST put /home/dadebidad/NS2/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14, /home/dadebidad/NS2/ns-allinone-2.35/lib, 
    into your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
    If it complains about X libraries, add path to your X libraries 
    into LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
    If you are using csh, you can set it like:
        setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
    If you are using sh, you can set it like:
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=

(2) You MUST put /home/dadebidad/NS2/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library  
into your TCL_LIBRARY environmental  
    variable. Otherwise ns/nam will complain during startup.
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is to be added to `.bashrc` .

The old year ~1999 text ....
»» Please put .... ,,   IMPORTANT NOTICES: You MUST put .. ««
.. was meant only for a "University Computer" : 
 I.e. when you had no write permissions to /usr/local/.

The executable 'ns' or "ns-[any-name]" is hard coded to know the location of it´s libraries:
`ns-allinone-2.35/{ lib/{libtcl*, tclConfig.sh, tcl8*/}, bin/tcsh8* }`.

This will usually do : `$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/ && sudo make install` 
I.e.  'make install' will copy 'ns' to /usr/local/bin/,  i.e. i.e.  a system PATH.

---

```
HOWTO, ns-2.35 :
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz   (The 2014 .. 2017 update)
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
./install
cd ns-2.35/
sudo make install
cp ns ns235-orig  (This is your backup)
sudo cp ns235-orig /usr/local/bin/
cd ../nam-1.15/
sudo make install
```

That's it. If you add some changes or a patch, the executable 'ns235-orig' can still be used for the default examples : `$ ns235-orig file.tcl`

Answer (score 0):

The Internal Field Separator for path variables is `:`. So assuming the libraries are in the locations listed in the output in your question. The following commands will properly populate the variables, if they are currently unset. The `~` should expand to your home dir.

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/NS2/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14:~/NS2/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
echo $TCL_LIBRARY
export TCL_LIBRARY=~/NS2/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library
```

Comment: I did the following. Did not conclude

Comment: @Dadebidad Did you run `.validate` or try rerunning the command that gave the error? If so was there a new error?